# Missing libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll Error when launching MinGW Compiled exe

Tags: c++, windows-7, mingw

I receive an error message when launching a MinGW compiled executable. I'm using a Windows 7 machine.

I have the MinGW bin directory in my Windows Path environment variable (checked and re-checked) and said dll does exist in that folder.

I understand I could move the dll to the exe directory but the application doesn't need to be distributed to anywhere that doesn't have a MinGW installation with the environment variable set up correctly (standard environment on our work machines). Many colleagues are using the same executable without an issue. The only difference I know of is that most (possibly all) colleagues are working on Windows XP, with me on Windows 7.

Additionally I do not have access to the build server to change the compiler flags to static link the library.

So despite the workarounds I mention, I want to get to the bottom of why it doesn't work with the current setup.

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers.

Comment: Does opening the executable file in depends.exe gives any additional information? A side by side configuration issue or something like that, for example.

Comment: By depends.exe do you mean the executable that I can't currently open because of the dependency?

Comment: depends.exe is a Microsoft tool 'Dependency Walker'. It lists all missing dll dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of mingw are you using? 4.4.0?

Download the package **`gcc-core-4.4.0-mingw32-dll.tar.gz`** from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/gcc/Version4/Previous%20Release%20gcc-4.4.0/).
Copy required dll from the `bin` folder into your mingw `bin` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wasn't sure if you had missed it in my first post when I said I already had the required DLLs in my MinGW/bin directory or whether you were getting at something else. So I went ahead and - after making a backup of the existing dlls (there was another one the exe depended on that I forgot to mention in my OP) - replaced it the ones I downloaded from the MinGW sourceforge site (for GCC 4.5.0) and it works, which is a little odd. Any ideas why windows can now find the DLLs after simply replacing them with the ones I downloaded? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: Hmm, things get a little more confusing. I can now launch the executable and the DLLs are found successfully in the MinGW directory. However, our company has a framework used for automated testing. When this framework is used to launch the executable it fails with the missing DLL error again. Obviously I don't expect anyone to be able to comment on why the framework may have issues, but it's just a bit of extra information I thought I'd add.

Comment: Did you copy the dll to `path` of your framework too? You can also put it into the same directory as the main executables.